# Coming from a Flash Builder background, how can I import a library into IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: actionscript-3, import, intellij-idea, libraries

the only IDE I've used for many years was Flash Builder. Sadly the 4.7 version is in a poor state, so, I started looking at other IDE's lately.

I'm trying IDEA, but I don't know how to add a library to my project.

In FB it was simple, I go to the compiler settings and I just add a folder or swc. But here, it seems like there are 2 options, one under the "Libraries" tab and other is creating a new module, however, this new module requires a main app, SDK, and a lot of other stuff that doesn't make any sense to have in a library.

So, what is the equivalent of adding a library path here?.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi dear, I find this: http://newtriks.com/2010/01/25/adding-library-swcs-to-intellij-idea-9/ I hope is useful

Answer (score 0):

"Libraries" is the correct way to do it. There are two kinds of libraries: libraries and global libraries. Global libraries can configured once and used in every project. Libraries are configured for each project. See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-project-and-global-libraries.html